# Create attribute with min/max value

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes

Hi I am trying to create attributes. I need to create an attribute which accepts any value between 1 to 9999. The code is as follows,

```
 $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'number_of_codes', array(
'type'              => 'text',
'backend'           => '',
'frontend'          => '',
'label'             => 'Number of Codes to Generate',
'input'             => 'select',
'class'             => '',
'source'            => 'catalog/product_attribute_source_layout',
'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'visible'           => false,
'required'          => false,
'user_defined'      => true,
'default'           => '1',
'searchable'        => false,
'filterable'        => false,
'comparable'        => false,
'visible_on_front'  => false,
'unique'            => false,
'group'             => 'Code_Generation'
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest might be to add a frontend validator where you attribute data is added.
Include validation.js on your page and add these class-attributes to your input field:

```
<input .... class="required-entry validate-digits-range digits-range-1-9999" />
```